# Error: 'anil' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11

why i am getting the error anil not declared in the scope even if it is declared in the main function ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct student
{
    int rollno,classa;
};
void initial(student *);
void display(student *);
int main()
{   student anil={10,11};
    initial(&anil);
    display(&anil);
    return 0;
}
void initial(student *)
{
    anil->rollno=100;anil->classa=10;}
void display(student *)
{
    cout<<anil->rollno<<anil->classa;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you should pass by reference, not by pointer.  This is C++ and C++ can use references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the `main` function does not extend to the `initial` function.  For a variable to be in scope, a reference to that variable has to be after the definition and before the closing curly brace that matches the most recent opening curly brace before the variable definition. You can also declare variables outside of any curly braces; they will be accessible anywhere after their declaration, but will also be implicitly `static`.

```
int a;

someFunc()
{
   int b;
} // This closing curly brace ends the scope of 'b'

int c = a + 1; // ok, a was declared outside any brace
```

Answer (score 1):

`anil` is declared inside `main()`, so it's local to it and invisible to other functions (i.e. its scope only extends to the end of `main()` body).

To access it from other functions you need to pass it as an argument to them (which you are already doing) *and* have the name for this argument in function's signature. So, in your case, you need to do something like this:

```
void initial(student * ps)
{
    ps->rollno=100;ps->classa=10;
}

void display(student * ps)
{
    cout<<ps->rollno<<ps->classa;
}
```

Now these functions will be able to access the pointer to `anil`, you are passing to them, under the name `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this would simply be to name the pointer parameter anil, like so

```
void initial(student *anil)
```